# TypeError: onLocation() missing 1 required positional argument: 'instance'

Tags: python, android, kivy

I am trying to make a kivy app that shows the devices current location via Plyer GPS. The code is below. When I run it the screen shows "Waiting for GPS data" and ADB Logcat says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
I/python  (12581):    File "jnius/jnius_proxy.pxi", line 50, in jnius.jnius.PythonJavaClass.invoke
I/python  (12581):    File "jnius/jnius_proxy.pxi", line 76, in jnius.jnius.PythonJavaClass._invoke
I/python  (12581):    File "/home/joshua/GPSapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/gpsApp/plyer/platforms/android/gps.py", line 24, in onLocationChanged
I/python  (12581):  TypeError: onLocation() missing 1 required positional argument: 'instance'
```

Code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import Image, AsyncImage
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.utils import platform

from random import randint as rando
import time
import socket
import certifi
import os
#import urllib.request

from plyer import gps

try:
    from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission, check_permission
except Exception as e:
    print('couldnt import android.permissions: ', e)

lat = "foo"
lng = "foo"
gpsData = "foo"
locationAble = True

class MyGrid(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        global lat
        global lng
        global locationAble
        global gpsData


        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1

        self.inside = GridLayout()
        self.inside.cols = 2

        #Starts GPS monitoring
        try:
            
            request_permissions([Permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                                    Permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION])
            
            try:
                while not check_permission('android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'):

                    print('Inside getLocationData(): Permissions have not been granted yet. Waiting .5 seconds')
                    time.sleep(.5)

                    pass

            except Exception as e:
                print('Couldnt loop waiting for permissions: ',e)

            try:
                gps.configure(on_location=self.onLocation)#, on_status=self.onStatus)
                print('gps.configure worked')

            except Exception as e:

                print('gps.configure failed: ', e)

            try:
                gps.start(minTime=1000,minDistance=1)
            except Exception as e:
                print("gps.start failed: ", e)

        except Exception as e:
            print("GPS monitering failed: ", e)
            locationAble = False

        if locationAble:

            self.add_widget(Label(text="Waiting for GPS data..."))

            pass

        else:

            self.add_widget(Label(text="Couldn't get GPS data"))

            pass


    def refreshScreen(self, instance):
        global gpsData

        print("Refreshing Screen")

        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(Label(text=gpsData))

    def onStatus(stype,status):
        global lat
        global lng

        print('inside onStatus')
        try:

            gps_status = 'type={}\n{}'.format(stype, status)
            print('finishing onStatus with gps_status as: ', str(gps_status))

        except Exception as e:

            print('failed inside onStatus: ', e)

    pass

    def onLocation(self, instance, **kwargs):

        global lat
        global lng
        global gpsData

        print('inside onLocation')
        try:

            gpsCycles = 0
            if gpsCycles == 0:

                try:
                    print('trying to print kwargs inside onLocation():')
                    print(kwargs)
                except exception as e:

                    print('failed to print kwargs: ',e)

                try:
                    gpsData = '<!>'.join([
                            '{}={}'.format(k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items()])

                except Exception as e:
                    print('Failed to get gps data inside onLocation: ', e)


                #Creates and assigns values to global variables lat and lng
                try:
                    print('trying to assign lat from kwargs...')
                    #lat = kwargs['lat']
                    #print('inside onLocation(): got lat: ',str(lat))
                except Exception as e:
                    print('inside onLocation(): failed to assign lat: ',e)

                try:
                    print('trying to assign lng from kwargs...')
                    #lng = kwargs['lon']
                    print('inside onLocation(): got lat: ',str(lat))
                except Exception as e:
                    print('inside onLocation(): failed to assign lng: ',e)


                try:
                    print('Inside onlocation(): trying to update gpsCycle...')
                    gpsCycles = gpsCycles + 1

                except Exception as e:
                    print('Inside onLocation(): Couldnt update gpsCycles: ',e)


            else:
                print('Inside onLocation(): this is an exccess call')

        except Exception as e:

            print('Inside onLocation(): Main try failed: ',e)

        try:
            print("Inside class.onLocation(): trying to refresh Screen...")
            self.refresh(instance)
            print("refreshed screen")
        except Exception as e:
            print("Failed to refresh Screen: ", e)



class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

What am I doing wrong? I suspect this is basic Python knowledge that I totally missed. I don't have a very deep understanding of python so please be patient with me. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, are you sure that the `on_location` callback should have an `instance` argument? [This example](https://github.com/kivy/plyer/blob/master/examples/gps/main.py#L66) in the Kivy github repo doesn't have such an argument. What's the difference between `instance` and `self` anyway?

Comment: Just so you know, in python `self` is the class instance. Hence the comment above about the use of `instance` here.